# Largest Product in MxN grid

Tags: code-golf

Given an MxN grid of numbers, find the greatest product of a length 4 subsequence in any row, column, or diagonal. Subsequences *cannot* wrap around (e.g. `5 1 2 3` in the row `1 2 3 4 5`).

I/O can be anything reasonable: files, stdin/stdout, copy+pasting expressions/arguments, variables. (If I'm missing any esoteric I/O option, feel free to go ahead and post your solution anyways)

Comment: Can we assume that all numbers are positive integers?

Comment: I see a no-brain method searching for every rows, every columns, etc. But I hardly see any solution beside straight forward. Also, once you solved this problem go validate it on euler project: http://projecteuler.net/problem=11

Comment: @Howard Yes -- although I would think that most solutions would generalize fine to negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 26 chars

```
>./,4*/\"1(,|:,]/.,]/.@|.)
```

Just an expression to which a rank 2 array could be appended.

`,|:,]/.,]/.@|.` takes the rank 2 array and concatenates 4 intermediate rank 2 arrays, the input's identity, transposition, and obliques, respectively. Here I feel like there's an uncomfortable amount of redundancy, because there are 2 `]`s, 3 `,`s, and 2 `/.`s... I can't think of a way to refactor those out.

`>./,4*/\"1` is just a straightforward maximum of each length 4 subsequence of each row of the newly made array, which of course corresponds to rows/columns/diagonals of the original.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 190

A 9x5 matrix.

```
m = RandomInteger[{1, 99}, {9, 5}];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

**Code**
This produces the product and the factors.

```
{e, f} = Dimensions@m; z = Reverse; w = Flatten;
j = Join[m, n = m\[Transpose], p = z /@ m, q = z /@ n, 
w[Table[Diagonal[#, k], {k, -(e - 4), f - 4}] & /@ {m, n, p, q}, 1]];
Sort[w[Partition[#, 4, 1] & /@ j, 1] /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {a b c d, {a, b, c, d}}][[-1]]
```

> {37714500, {90, 85, 58, 85}}